# How does $y^{1-q}$ become $x^{(1-q)/q}$ in this proof of the formula for the derivative of rational powers?

Tags: calculus

I don't understand a proof step in my calculus textbook (Calculus one and several variables, Salas). It's supposed to be a proof of the derivative of rational powers, but I don't understand the 3rd line from the bottom.

How did they get $y^{1-q}$ to equal $x^{(1-q)/q}\,$?

[image: proof of rational power derivatives]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $y=x^{\frac{1}{q}}$ by assumption, so substitution tells us that $y^{1-q}=(x^{\frac{1}{q}})^{1-q}=x^{\frac{1-q}{q}}$. This uses the fact that an exponent raised to another exponent is equivalent to multiplying the exponents together; the "power rule for exponents."

Comment: Ah that makes sense, thanks!

Comment: @CuriousMathPerson sure thing! Also, you can hit the check mark on the side to accept the answer if you feel it answered the question.